# Modernizr is not detecting features within IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, virtualbox, modernizr

For some strange reason, the Modernizr script will not run detection on featuers within the IE8 browser, well at least I think it doesn't.

Anyway, I am using a CMS where I cannot insert the "no-js" class into the HTML tag when I create a page - but this does not seem to bother all the other web browsers (including more recent versions of IE). Modernizr is able to inject the classes into the HTML tag even though the "no-js" class is not initially present (thank god). I have checked and verified this when using the various browser implementations of "inspect element".

I am testing IE8 in Virtual Box using an install vdi from ModernIE.

I have a specific class when Modernizr detects there is no support for SMIL SVG animation but IE8 does not seem to use it. I have a div whereby I am using an animated SVG file as the background image. What IE8 does is just display the background colour of the div and not the specific Modernizr fallback class which tells the browser to use a static PNG file as the background image. Could also be due to the face I am using background: cover property which is also not supported (but I assume I would still see the png file but just not stretched out to cover the dimensions of the div.

I'll outline the css I am using below:

```
.jumbotron.handwriting.dark{
    background: #CD4833 url('http://qanzac100.slq.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/file/0007/283939/textpattern.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    /*z-index: 4;*/
}

/* Modernizr fallback for browsers that do not support SVG SMIL animation. Replaces bg image with static png file */
.no-smil .jumbotron.handwriting.dark{
    background: url('http://qanzac100.slq.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/image/0004/284017/textpattern.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Now I have looked over the Modernizr website quite a few times and I don't see anywhere where it says that it does not support IE8. Is there perhaps something that I am doing obviously wrong here? It works in IE11 and switches over as that browser still does not support SMIL.

I have yet to try this in IE9, but will do so shortly.

**Update:** IE9 works fine as it actually does support SVG object. I did a test run myself at here www.coolwebs.com.au/svgTest/ without putting it in the CMS we are using and it seemed to work. Not sure what's causing it but the problem only seems to be in IE8. I have modernizr working on IE11 when detecting for a workaround for SMIL SVG animation.

Comment: what version of modernizr are you using?

Comment: The latest version, 2.8.3

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. The test page for modernizr 2.8.3 shows `smil: false` and adds the `.no-smil` class to the html element. Can you share the page that shows the issue?

Comment: That's kind of difficult as the environment is behind a secure CMS and it's a live site under development. However, what I will endeavour to do is do a mockup on another hosting domain and see what happens from there. Who knows, the SQUIZ Matrix CMS could be making the issue.

Comment: Crumbs, it appears as though the CMS is causing the grief. Here is an example I just put up (quick and fast) and it works: www.coolwebs.com.au/svgTest/

Comment: Happy to try and help if you are able to get a broken version up anywhere. otherwise - good luck